# Text validation for Windows applications

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, sikuli

I'm writing automation tests for a windows application using Sikuli/Robotframework, I want to be able to validate text that I see on the application but the values change so would be using a variable created at the start of each test run, is there anyway to validate that the text value is present in the application using Sikuli if not where should I look for validation?

Comment: I think you need to add some more details about what technology, language etc that is used in the Windows application you are about to test.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at [SikuliLibrary](http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html#Get%20Text)

There is a Keyword called "Get Text" where it returns the text when an image file is passed. You can then store it in a variable and then make use of String comparison operation.

**Get text - from library**

Two ways in which you can retrieve text.

1. If image is not given, keyword will get text from whole Screen
2. If image is given, keyword will get text from matched region Call keyword setOcrTextRead to set OcrTextRead as true, before using text recognition keywords.

Examples:

```
Set Ocr Text Read   true
Get Text    
Get Text    test.png
```

**String comparison operation**

```
Should be equal as strings    ${only value}    ${sele}
```